# what does this mean @-moz-document url-prefix()

Tags: html, css

I tried in google but couldn't find good answer , what does the below code mean in css

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{

 .className {
  }

}
```

Is it saying that execute the code only for firefox , if so is it good way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [@-moz-document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document) means that the following only applies to Gecko browsers.

the `url-prefix()` states that the following only applies when the beginning of the url matches what is passed in the `url-prefix()` method.

An example:

```
url-prefix(http://www.domain.com/page1/)
```

So the follow css will only apply when that beginning of the page's url begins with http://domain.com/page1/

Answer (score 1):

> The `@-moz-document` rule is a Gecko-specific at-rule that restricts the style rules contained within it based on the URL of the document. It is designed primarily for user style sheets.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document).

Its primary use is in making your own stylesheets to customise your Firefox browsing experience.